# What brain chemical(s) is attributed to the deep satisfaction of achieving an important, meaningful, or long-term goal?

Tags: brain

What brain chemical(s) is attributed to the deep satisfaction of achieving an important, meaningful or long-term goal?

My understanding is that the shallow satisfaction of achieving an unimportant or short-term goal, such as

- Getting a handful of likes on social media
- Completing a mission in a video game
- Correctly answering a question in a classroom

is mostly attributed to dopamine.

Do larger-scale successes, such as

- Breaking a world record after $1000$ hours of unsuccessful attempts
- Winning a large chess tournament
- Learning a new skill

correspond to a different chemical or set of chemicals?

Answer (score 2):

### Serotonin and Dopamine

Serotonin contributes to satisfaction [0], and tends to have more background-level effects (so something that would be present while working on your project as well as after) than dopamine, while dopamine is associated with accomplishment in general [1], big or small (it's the "reward mechanism").

The most significant increase at the moment of accomplishment would be in dopamine, but serotonin would also increase.

[0] https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4449495/

[1] https://doi.org/10.1038/d41586-019-01589-6